# How to concatenate using Python Script Widget in Orange

Tags: orange

How to do concatenate in Python Script widget in Orange Data Mining software ?

table_1 = Table

table_2 = Table

how to concatenate table_1 and table_2 ?

Answer (score 0):

[`Table.concatenate`](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/blob/1012e20d37adf37e6d9a9645cac4d713e1817a3b/Orange/data/table.py#L933-L966) doesn't work?

```
table_12 = Table.concatenate([table_1, table_2], axis=0)
```